# Disabling all commands over SSH

Tags: windows, ssh, copssh

Suppose use can ssh to the server and can execure FTP and connect to other sources, download a virus and execute it.

Is it possible to force user to execute only some known commands?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you included more details about what users normally will be using this server for.  What are some of the typical activities you wish to permit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from `man sshd_config`:

> **ForceCommand**
>
> Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand ignoring any command supplied by the client and ~/.ssh/rc if present. The command is invoked by using the user's login shell with the -c option. This applies to shell, command, or subsystem execution. It is most useful inside a Match block. The command originally supplied by the client is available in the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment variable. Specifying a command of “internal-sftp” will force the use of an in-process sftp server that requires no support files when used with ChrootDirectory

this lets you use a shell wrapper that lets only do specific things.  one example is [rssh](http://dragontoe.org/rssh/).

If you only want this restriction for specific users, use the `command=cmd` option in the `known_hosts` file (documented in `man sshd`)

Comment: If you want to restrict ForceCommand to specific users,groups or hosts, you can also use the Match directive in sshd_config.

Answer (score 0):

One method, while not perfect, would be to create a separate partition for the users home directories any locations which they have write access.  The simply mount those partitions **noexec**.

Proper setup of file-system permissions will generally be very effective to limit the damage that can be done.

If the users are not at least somewhat trusted, then perhaps it is a bad idea to give them SSH access at all.  Perhaps you need to setup VMs for them and confine each to their own environment.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `noexec`?

Comment: Also, this general suggestion can giver a false sense of security. You'd need to lock down `/tmp` as well as any other globally writable directories, such as `/var/tmp`. This causes trouble for some package managers, which need someplace to unpack scripts that need to be run for proper configuration.

Comment: Yes, noexec.  The typo has been corrected.

Comment: RE: Sense of security the restricted shell alternative also has problems. People aren't careful and they permit applications which are able to launch sub-shells.  If you are really paranoid, you really need to combine all of the above.  A restricted shell and strong well-audited permissions setup.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting up a chroot environment for your users could help. See [How can I chroot ssh connections?](https://serverfault.com/questions/39997/how-can-i-chroot-ssh-connections)