# Special SSH Configuration

Tags: linux, ssh, users

At the moment in my sshd_config I have it set so that passwords cannot be used and only keys can be used to login.

I need to enable passwords for one user. This user is yet to be created and has to be a severely locked down user. Only able to see their own home directory and can only execute the basic commands (cd, mkdir, nano, etc...) inside their directory.

So my question is: how do I create this locked down user and how do I allow 'it' to login via ssh using a password?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

This tutorial has how to [chroot ssh/sftp users](http://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny).  Essentially, you'll need to create a configuration section at the end of sshd_config like

```
Match User username
    ChrootDirectory /home/somewhere
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

Add to that the `PasswordAuthentication Yes` (or ChallengeResponseAuthentication, whichever you're using) instruction to allow that user to use passwords.

If you want to ensure that the user can't create their own commands (you'd be surprised what you can do with bash) you'll need to make sure that everything in /home/somewhere is not owned by the user and not writable by the user.

That tutorial also links to [a script](http://www.fuschlberger.net/programs/ssh-scp-sftp-chroot-jail/) for finding all the prerequisites of the commands you want to add to the jail and building your chroot jail.

Answer (score 4):

The lock down part of your question is already answered at the question [How can I chroot ssh connections?](https://serverfault.com/questions/39997/how-can-i-chroot-ssh-connections).

Per user configuration can be achieved by the `Match` section as others have posted.