# Jail User to /var/www/username Directory via SSH

Tags: security, ssh, permissions, lamp, chroot

I have multiple folders in /var/www for different websites -- Apache uses name-based Virtual Hosts (Ubuntu Server). Suppose I want to allow someone to access their /var/www/user directory, but not cd out of it and be able to traverse the system.

I found information about an OpenSSH Jail here: http://antitese.org/sshjail/

Has anyone used/implemented something like this? Is there a better way aside from basic permissions to control this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I chroot ssh connections?](http://serverfault.com/questions/39997/how-can-i-chroot-ssh-connections)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently implemented it for a client. The concern was that many sensitive files are readable by anyone with SSH access, so I followed the [instructions on Limiting Access with SFTP Jails on Debian and Ubuntu](http://library.linode.com/security/sftp-jails) at Linode and it has worked fine since.

I did have to fiddle around with permissions quite a bit -- permissions have to be set exactly as described. Also, I found error messages (I think in /var/log/auth.log) to be surprisingly helpful.