# Chroot an SSH user under Linux? (OpenSSH)

Tags: linux, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I chroot ssh connections?](https://serverfault.com/questions/39997/how-can-i-chroot-ssh-connections)

I want to allow a friend of mine access to a server via SSH. Is there a way to "chroot" him to his home directory? I found a lot of guides that focus on SCP/SFTP, but I mean SSH. So he should be able to log in with `ssh -l accountname mybox` and should see only his home directory, but nothing up that level.