# Chroot with SSH connections doesn't work

Tags: ssh, chroot, debian-wheezy

I have found [How can I chroot ssh connections?](https://serverfault.com/q/39997/71177) and a lot of different blog articles and similar (http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20080220110039, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14398/57364, etc). I am using the internal sftp subsystem like described in the articles.

```
Subsystem     sftp   internal-sftp

Match Group www-data
  ChrootDirectory %h
  AllowTcpForwarding no
```

I can connect and authenticate with the server, but the SSH session is instantly closed.

Here is a part of the auth.log:

```
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: Accepted publickey for network from xxx port 50280 ssh2
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: debug1: monitor_child_preauth: network has been authenticated by privileged process
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user network by (uid=0)
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: User child is on pid 363
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[363]: debug1: SELinux support disabled
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[363]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: debug1: session_new: session 0
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: debug1: SELinux support disabled
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: debug1: session_by_tty: session 0 tty /dev/pts/1
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: debug1: session_pty_cleanup: session 0 release /dev/pts/1
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: debug1: PAM: closing session
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user network
Feb 18 23:36:21 w sshd[358]: debug1: PAM: deleting credentials
```

What is wrong?

**EDIT:**
I got following message on the client side:

```
/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why it is a problem.
I thought with the "new" version of OpenSSH the copy part is past?

Comment: Check your _other_ log files. Debian is silly and splits the log six different ways...

Comment: @MichaelHampton There is a message on the client side. :)

Comment: Are you trying to use SFTP or to get an interactive shell via SSH?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It feels like you're trying to get an interactive shell into a `chroot` jail. The SFTP subsystem has nothing to do with that because you're not SFTP'ing.

You *do* need to populate the jail with the necessary files to allow the user to execute a shell. That means creating a `/bin` directory relative to the jail root and populating it with a copy of `/bin/bash` (among other things).

The [Jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/) utility is capable of building up chroot jails automatically and is being actively maintained. You may want to have a look there.

If you're into doing things manually have a look at the following (particularly the first, since you're using Debian):

- [Securing Debian Manual: Appendix G - Chroot environment for SSH](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ap-chroot-ssh-env.en.html)
- [Creating a Chroot Jail for SSH Access](http://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access)
- [Chroot users with OpenSSH](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/chroot-users-with-openssh-an-easier-way-to-confine-users-to-their-home-directories/229/)
- [An answer on the question you linked](https://serverfault.com/a/435954/7200)